# How to get last commit SHA in a specific branch from a remote repository

Tags: git

I would like to know if I can easily get the last commit sha from a remote repository and a specific branch.
I could do a
`git fetch MY_REMOTE_REPO;git checkout BRANCH_X;git log -1;` but it is heavy just to get a SHA string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ls-remote`](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/13/list-remote-branches.html) plumbing command does exactly this.  For example, to see the sha1 of the current `master` branch in the Linux kernel:

```
$ git ls-remote http://www.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git master
5f90b6fa0f5cf1d06bc72ffe607be3cd6aa955b5    refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing easier than that.

```
git ls-remote MY_REMOTE_REPO
```